# How to implement a tokenizer and parser?

Tags: python

I want to make a tokenizer, and then a parser in python.

The idea of the tokenizer is to convert a string in a list of words.

If my string is  `"(define x 5) ( + (* 2 x) 7)"`

the tokenizer should output

```
['(', 'define', 'x', '5', ')', '(', '+' , '(', '*', '2', 'x',')', '7', ')']
```

then the parser should convert that list into:

```
[('define', 'x', 5) , ('+', ('*', 2, 'x'), 7)]
```

I'm a bit lost and have no idea on how to start.

All I have is:

```
def tokenizer(a):
    final=[]
    return final
```

Comment: Iterate through the string and look what category the char belongs to.

Comment: We don't write code, we only debug it. Seeing as there is nothing to debug here we can't answer your question.

Comment: Megalng, what do you mean by category? to the tokenizer i dont need to see if its a char or not.
Aparently the easiest way, is to add a space in the '(' and after that, use the split function right? i just dont know how to add the spaces

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro, _"i just dont know how to add the spaces"_ -- so, is that all you want to know?

Comment: yes, how can i add spaces before and after '(' and ')'

Becouse even if i end up with extra spaces, the split funcion will ignore them, leaving me with the words i need

Answer (score 0):

You should start by thinking more about the problem, not by writing code.

In particular, think about what exactly your "words" are. What are your various kinds of words? Look especially at the words that can use more than one character. How can you recognize the start of that kind of word? How can you recognize a continuation, and how can you recognize the end of the word? Also, exactly what would be an error in constructing a word?

After you have answers to all those questions, then you can consider beginning to code. Until then, you have no idea what to code.

We do not have all your specifications, so we cannot answer those questions for you even if we want to. We could make guesses based on your example, but they would only be guesses.

Comment: For now, all i want is to split the characters between spaces so i can have the list of "words" to manipulate. The easiest way is to add spaces after the '(' so i can use the split function

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro: But your example also does not have a space before the right parentheses `')'`. Also part of your thought process--are you guaranteed to have spaces where they would be convenient for you? Are you sure that the only the parentheses will lack surrounding spaces? Again, you need either the complete problem specification or much more context to be able to answer those questions.

Answer (score 0):

> @EduardoRibeiro, "i just dont know how to add the spaces" -- so, is
>   that all you want to know? – palivek
>
> yes, how can i add spaces before and after '(' and ')' – Eduardo
>   Ribeiro

I would go with `listcomp`:

```
def expander(exp):
    special = ('(', ')')
    return ''.join(c if c not in special else c + ' ' for c in exp)
```

Which would give:

```
>>> expander("(define x 5) ( + (* 2 x) 7)")
'( define x 5)  (  + ( * 2 x)  7) '
```

**EDIT:**

> that wont work becouse i need spaces between 5 and ) and between 7 and
>   ) But you gave me the general idea, thank you – Eduardo Ribeiro 13
>   mins ago

```
def expander(exp):
    chars = ('(', ')')
    return ''.join(c if c not in chars else ' ' + c + ' ' for c in exp)
```

Which gives:

```
>>> expander("(define x 5) ( + (* 2 x) 7)")
' ( define x 5 )   (  +  ( * 2 x )  7 ) '
```

Comment: This isn't your **original** question though, so I feel a bit guilty.

Comment: that wont work becouse i need spaces between 5 and )
and between 7 and )
But you gave me the general idea, thank you

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro You can just change `c + ' '` to 
`' '  + c + ' '` , and that should do the trick.

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro, what do you mean? `>>> def expander(exp):
    chars = ('(', ')')
    return ''.join(c if c not in chars else ' ' + c + ' ' for c in exp)

>>> expander("(define x 5) ( + (* 2 x) 7)")
' ( define x 5 )   (  +  ( * 2 x )  7 ) '`

Comment: expander("(define x 5)") returns define x 5

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro, have a look at the edit and report back.

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro, also, if you plan to implement a full-fledged Lisp, you might be better of using regular expressions to do the parsing.

Comment: i ended up using the replace function.
def expander:
s=a.replace('(',' ( ')
t=s.replace(')',' ) ')
return t

Answer (score -1):

```
def expander(a):
s=a.replace('(',' ( ')

t=s.replace(')',' ) ')

return t

def tokenizer(a):

s=expander(a)

final=s.split()

return final
```

this is the code for tokenizer

Comment: That "code" has bad indentation and therefore will not run at all. This "answer" does not actually answer the question. That is so even though you wrote both the question and the answer. Please edit the question and the answer to be more clear. If you do that you may get upvotes. You also do not address any of the issues I ask in my answer. You are allowed to answer your own question here, but the answer should really be an answer.